# How to add "UP" back button in fragment (Fragment to Activity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I want to go from fragment to activity using back button using toolbar back icon.

[image: like this one]

The fragment is my navigation drawer item & activity is my MainActivity.

How do I do it?

Comment: what did you do to create it?

Answer (score 24):

You can use `app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"` for that back navigation icon.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"/>
```

For navigation:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (ToolBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarId);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Inside your layout file.

Comment: error shown : app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator

Comment: Remove that collapseMode

Comment: but still shown error in  (app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator") (app is red colour)

Comment: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" Use this in your parent layout.

Comment: You can also use: `alt plus enter key`

Comment: yes now fix, but where put this code, in fragment (Toolbar toolbar = (ToolBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarId);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });)

Comment: Inside `onViewCreated`.

Comment: after put this code on onViewCreated toolbar id is not shown & (ToolBar), onBackPressed(); red in colour...

Comment: you can implement your own instead of `onBackPress` method. Like Intent to move from one to another. you haven't said what to do by that back button.  you have to import toolbar: `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
`

Comment: sir if you provide email id then I send my code please help me

Comment: There is back icon or not in the view.

Comment: You are not using mine suggestion?

Comment: Sir this is my project file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8YTgurIRbm5R0ozVjFINFVERW8  (I want to toobar back function)

Answer (score 7):

Call this method in your fragment onCreateView

```
public void showBackButton() {
if (getActivity() instanceof ActionBarActivity) {
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: inside the fragment onCreateView

Comment: after put this code (return v;) v is red, I am put this code after (return v;) but still shown red what to do

Comment: this shows thee toolbar, but it doesn't navigate back to the previous fragment..

Answer (score 4):

Try this worked for me :

1. in XML:

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/profileToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   ```
2. Create an back arrow icon in drawable folder. Name it 'ic_back_button'. 
   Not sure how :-
   just right click on drawable > new > ImageAsset > Clip Art > Search back > select > OK > Finish (don't forget to change the name).
3. then Inside your fragment in onCreateView :

   ```
       Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.profileToolbar);
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_button);
       toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         getActivity().onBackPressed();
       }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It might help in case if you want to come back from fragment to previous location.

Put this in your class with navController.

```
  @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    navController.navigateUp();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

don't forget implement relevant dependency such as navigation and navigation UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add this xml code to your fragment and try

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title Here"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivback_water"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I asked you to add this code in xml after that check in design part. no need any fragment code for this

Comment: Once the back button is visible make intent call to it to go from fragment to activity

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that, if you are using a **Custom** back button that is placed on your **Custom** top app bar, in the button's `onClick()` function you can call.. `getActivity().onBackPressed();`
it would work the same as if you have clicked the android navigation's back button...